# find a distance between object in binary image

Tags: matlab, object, image-processing, binary

I have a binary image with two white vertical segments separated by a small gap. I would like to calculate the distance between the two segments. Or better the gap.

My first attempt: find the profile of the two segments (using bwboundary and bwtraceboundary) and then find the intersection between this profile with horizontal line scanning the whole image. The number of lines without intersection represents the distance between the two segments.

I would like to find this gap without detecting the profile. Is there a way? 
Thank you.

Comment: I am confused,  could you post the image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [measuretool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25964-image-measurement-utility) from the MATLAB File Exchange by Jan Neggers to retrieve geometrical information of images.

Comment: If you have series of images and doing want to do the graphical calculations then I would suggest to you a profiling approach. Take a horizontal profile (assuming you have only two segments which are vertical). The measure the write a small script to find the euclidean distance between the peaks of this profile. The measure distance would be in terms of squre pixels.